# How to get a material to keep the transparent border from it's texture

Tags: texturing, materials

I tried almost everything from fiddling with import properties, to adding a Transparent BDSF (As answered in other questions I found on this site) yet nothing seems to work...

below is the picture, that appears, it's in material view, and I also tried switching to rendered view.

[image]

Comment: Usually you take the alpha component from the Image texture node and use it as the factor in the Mix Shader node. Where the other inputs are a Transparent BSDF and a Diffuse BSDF(with its input set to the colour from the Image texture node.

Comment: @rob did that, it still didn't work

Comment: can you show us the nodes or upload the .blend file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: done, do I need to upload the texture files as well?

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5755" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5755/)

Comment: yes, or use the File/ External Data/ Pack All to store the files in the .blend.

Comment: updated, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5773" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5773/)      .

 
here's a link to zip containing all the files just in case
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tOg961VfPnLDITZHKvFSiyoPPog6P3Gd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have added a **Color/Invert Node** to swap the Black/White of your texture before feeding it into the **Color** of the **Mix Shader**

[image]
[image]
[image]

On the left is with the Invert node and on the right without. Showing what is and what is not being transparent.

[image]

and the final result.

FYI For more control plug the **Alpha** into the **Factor** on the **Invert Node** and then change the colour.

Comment: and of course you do not need the Invert Node just swap around the inputs.